# Output custom code In a specific WooCommerce product page if out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm trying to **check if the user is on a specific product page**, then **if the product is out of stock**. If the product is not in stock, I want to display an optional promo image that adds another product to cart.

With the current code I get an error and the page stops rendering when it reaches this snippet.

Right now my code is as follows:

```
<?php if (! $product->is_in_stock() && is_single('12005') ) { ?> 

        <div id="oos-promo">
            <a href="https://example.com/?add-to-cart=11820&quantity=1">
                <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/product.jpg" alt="Promo" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

I'm putting this code in the `content-single-product.php` file nested immediately inside the `"entry-summary"` element on this template file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! My mistake was not pulling in the global $product variable prior to the if statement, see final code below:

```
<?php global $product; if (! $product->is_in_stock() && is_single('12005') ) { ?> 

    <div id="oos-promo">
        <a href="https://example.com/?add-to-cart=11820&quantity=1">
            <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/product.jpg" alt="Promo" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding WooCommerce templates you should embed your code in a function hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** action hook, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'out_of_stock_custom_code', 3 );
function out_of_stock_custom_code() {
    // Including the WC_Product object
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_id() == 12005 ) {
        ?>
        <div id="oos-promo">
            <a href="?add-to-cart=11820&quantity=1">
                <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/product.jpg" alt="Promo" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php file.

This code Is tested and works.

Comment: Very good approach! Let's say that I want to remove `woocommerce_template_single_price` function if product is out of stock, would your answer will be a proper way of doing it, or should I consider some other approaches?